# Why will my Google Map API not render?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to do a simple Google Map API integration into my WordPress website. When the user initially goes onto the website they should be able to see the location of the base I have set. Then if they click the button it should display their current location. However, they are currently not rendering/displaying. It worked earlier, however I must have changed something before and overrode the current file. Any help would be appreciated as I really don't know where this has gone wrong!

Code:

```js
// JavaScript Document

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.843143, -2.643555),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  $("#findButton").click(findMe);
}

function errorCallback() {
  alert("I'm afraid your browser does not support geolocation.");]

function successCallback(position) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
}

function findMe() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    console.log(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {
      timeout: 10000
    }));
  } else {
    alert("I'm afraid your browser does not support geolocation.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. You have bracket instead of brace.

```
function errorCallback() {
    alert("I'm afraid your browser does not support geolocation.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error:

```
function errorCallback (){
    alert("I'm afraid your browser does not support geolocation.");] 
    //                                                            ^^^
```